No CORS error when I try to run an AWS Lambda function via a REST API. I've tried EVERY potential fix/solution I can find online. No luck
Trying to trigger my Lambda function via an API call (set up through API Gateway) in my JS code.
I get the No CORS error despite enabling CORS, having the Header Mappings set up to this in the Integration Response section:
|| || |method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials|'true'| |method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers|'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'| |method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods|'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'| |method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin|'*'| |method.response.header.Access-Control-Expose-Headers|'Content-Type, X-Amz-Date, Authorization, X-Api-Key, X-Amz-Security-Token'|
and despite overtly returning the headers in the Lambda Function response itself:
return {

statusCode: 200,

headers: {

'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': '*', // Allow credentials

'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token', // Headers allowed in requests

'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT', // Allowed HTTP methods

'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Origin allowed for CORS (use '*' to allow all origins or specify a domain)

'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Type, X-Amz-Date, Authorization, X-Api-Key, X-Amz-Security-Token' // Expose these headers to the client

},

body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'CORS settings applied successfully' })

};

I've really also tried just about every variation of all of those things you can imagine: Including/excluding every one of those items from the header response, from the header mappings, making sure all match perfectly, setting up only some in the response, etc etc. And yes, I deploy the API and deploy the Lambda Function code changes each time.
Literally none of the fixes I've read on every StackOverflow post are working here. I am simply out of ideas and above to just give up on this entirely.
Any ideas? Thanks.
Error will either say:
"...has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."
OR
"...has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."
My JS:
    async function callLambda() {
    const apiKey = '123123blahblah';  // omitted for StackOverflow post
    const lambdaData = {
        'message': 'hello'
    };

    const lambdaInvokeUrl = 'https://blah123.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/blahblah1';

    try {
        const response = await fetch(lambdaInvokeUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Api-Key': apiKey
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(lambdaData)
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const result = await response.json();
        console.log("RESPONSE:", result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    }
}

Integration Request settings (for the ANY) section:

Integration Response settings (for the OPTIONS section):

Default Gateway Responses 4xx and 5xx are set up with the same headers

Firstly, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is a boolean that can only be set to true, you seem to have it set to *. Secondly, when Access-Control-Allow-Origin is *, then credentials are not allowed for security reasons. See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials
You need to configure explicit origin list if you want to use credentials

Thanks for the tips -- I updated those things and still I receive the same error.

Which of the two errors? You say sometimes it's this error, sometimes another? Does it change randomly without you changing anything? Can you post an update of your exact Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials settings now?

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*',
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT',
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',

"...has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled." is the one that is currently and consistently showing up

And if you inspect the response of the server in the Network tab of Dev Tools, what headers does it include to the preflight OPTIONS request that fetch sends? Does it include all those that you've set and expect? Is there indeed some middleware that might be stripping those headers from the response?

General:
Request URL: https://blah123.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/blah456
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 123.456.789.1011
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Response Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

In the API Gateway Resources tab, I had to click on ANY, and for Integration Response, and Method Response, I had to make the header mappings EXACTLY match the exact setup of the OPTIONS. That's what made it work.
